# is this a good workout plan for beginners

Tags: workout-routines

So im  trying a 30 day workout plan and I was wondering if this is ok it starts with the first week being 2 sets then the second 3 sets then the third week 4 sets and the 4th week being five sets.

It starts at 30 lunges, 30 sit ups, 30 push ups,2x30 second planks, 20 burbeeries and 10 crunches and each day I add five to each and every 4th day I rest.

Is this ok ? Im new to the whole thing

Comment: Do you mean burpees?

Comment: See some related thoughts here: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/15334/5605

Comment: Do you have to do them all at the same time? Unless you're really fit, you won't complete the 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how healthy you are already because if you are already reasonably fit then it would be a very good routine as long as a few breaks were put in between 5-10 mins, but if your looking to get fit then i would say maybe start off with it a little easier because you may not be able to do all of this in the first week maybe build it up gradually in the first week? until you are able to do the routine better. Although i would personally try your routine on the first day if i were you to see if you are capable of it yet and if so then stick with it, but if not then it's whatever you believe you are capable of doing from what you achieved in that day. You should also warm up and warm down sometimes to ensure you don't pull something even if it's just a little work out to ensure you don't strain something. But yes i think it's  good :)

Comment: I did this routine today and im fairly fit and healthy but id say its harder than I thought but its challenges me ever ao slightly so I think ill stick to this for the first week

Comment: Good idea it should be something you can accomplish but be reasonably hard to complete so you are achieving more. If your routine is good like you say then not much variation will be needed for the first week or so just rise it slowly throughout the month.

Answer (score 0):

That workout is a good start to get your body used to moving and get you in the habit of incorporating exercise into your life permanently, which is vital for any long-term benefit. Find movements that challenge you but are also enjoyable in some way at least, and which can fit into your life.