# Planning My Workout

Tags: workout-routines

I'm a 16 year old a little fat girl and I have some problems with my body shape. I have a pear shaped body shape and I want to get rid of that as much as it's possible. I want to be fit and healthy. So I'm preparing a workout plan for myself by researching but I couldn't decide which one is the best for me.

I'll be very happy if you guys help me figure out which one is the best for me.

I don't to be like the girls who have big muscles and heavy thighs and big triceps. I just want to look fit. You know like this girl:
http://data1.whicdn.com/images/45317953/large.jpg

So here are my questions:

1- Which exercises do I need to do and how many days in a week should i do? (Like squats, crunches etc.)

2- Should I make a plan like
Monday- leg day
Wednesday-abs day
Saturday- arm day

or should I mix them and do the same exercises everyday like
Everyday- squats, bike crunches, wall sit,arm lifts etc.

If you can recommend anything that can be beneficial for me please do because I really need help from somebody that knows this stuff.

P.s. I'm gonna start working out regularly for the first time.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "16 y/o little fat girl"? While the girl in the picture is thin, she also has very little actual muscle tone, and is most likely underweight. She fits the societal image of attraction, but may not be healthy. If you gave more details such as your actual height/weight, typical daily diet, and any exercise you currently do answers could be much more detailed and informative.

Comment: Well, supposedly she's never coming back. Ah well, other people will read this so: Girls, you will _not_ get bulky if you don't try _hard, for years_. Believe me, I'm trying and it's extremely slow going. You're not the 0.01% that builds muscle unnaturally fast, so don't worry. And yes, I know other people said that already, but I feel like in this time and age of fitness it can't be said often enough.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to know is that there are as many workout routines and philosophies as there are people working out, so everybody's going to have a different opinion.

The second thing you need to know is that getting heavy thighs and triceps should be very low on your list of concerns. It's just not likely, and if it ever happens then you've got a better problem to deal with than being fat.

If you're really serious about this, then I'm not really going to be able to cover everything you need to know in this answer, but I would recommend that you grab the following book to learn the fundamentals of weight training:

[Starting Strength](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0982522738)

Third, you're not going to reach your goal without a combination of exercise and diet. However,  what I want to stress is please do not go on a crazy crash diet. The crazier and more difficult your diet, the higher the likelihood that you're going to fail.

Start slow. Take a month and pick one of the most unhealthy things that you eat on a regular basis and then stop eating it. Focus on sweets (esp soft drinks or fruit juice) and really high calorie things. That's it... Don't change anything else.

Then, if you're successful in the next few months pick a few more things and do those.  For everything else, don't stress too much. Just make little deals with yourself. If you really want the bacon cheeseburger, then compromise on just a regular burger.  Or if you have a really unhealthy lunch, try to eat something healthy for dinner.

One thing people don't realize is that dieting is really permanent behavior change. If you stop drinking soft drinks, then after six months or a year you'll stop wanting soft drinks, and after more than a year you'll probably think they taste gross.

Just don't overdo it.

Now, on to the strength training.

You'll read about this in the book, but you'll probably want to target your workouts to 12 rep sets for a good combination of muscle growth and endurance. You do want muscle growth, because that's what burns calories. After six months or so, I would bump up the reps to 15 or maybe a tad more to focus more on endurance than muscle growth.  At that point you could also look at circuit training to get more cardio involved.

In the book there is a very simple workout routine. Just keep it simple. Focus on big exercises and not isolations. Along the same vein, it's a myth that you can isolate problem areas (like fat thighs) with thigh specific exercises. The fat's going to come off where it wants to, and the large whole body exercises are going to be more effective at that.

Make up your mind that you're going to be in it for the long haul. The first couple of months are going to be horrible. You will be tired, sore, and you will have less energy. All of this changes after about two or three months, and you'll start to have more energy and you will feel stronger.

Also, every week try to increase your weight by a small amount on your exercises. This is where the motivation comes in. When you come back in two months and you're now lifting 30% more than you did when you started, that's motivating.

**Always warm up with a mile or so on the cardio machine or elliptical or you'll hurt yourself**

**Pay lots of attention to the proper way to do exercises or you'll end up with tendinitis because of disproportionate joint loading and other things. You do not want this.**

Comment: Starting Strength is primarily a Squat/Deadlift/Bench Press routine. Squats and Deadlifts targets thighs and Bench targets triceps. The OP stated they don't want big thighs or tricps. **Your suggestion runs completely counter to what was asked.**

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr There's a big difference between gaining muscle mass and being musclebound, which is what I assume the asker is worried about. A sensible lifting routine will help her lose fat in the most efficient way and will also help her overall health. Others might recommend a death march cardio routine, but I won't. I do think you're wrong about your downvote though.

Comment: See here for female results on the starting strength program for weight loss:  http://i.imgur.com/1Ws5S.jpg

Comment: Whats wrong with cardio? Some of us enjoy running? And with a good diet and some auxilliary exercises it can be just as successful and healthy as anything else.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I didn't say there's anything wrong with it, I just didn't recommend it as the cornerstone in this specific case. If you'd like to recommend a cardio program to her, then feel free to answer the question yourself.

Comment: You said "cardio death march". Call me crazy but "death march" doesn't exact bring up positive connotations. Also, I wasn't planning on writing an answer, *I'm critiquing yours* for not addressing the OPs requirements, and instead, blindly recommending Starting Strength.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr This post basically explains my position on cardio versus weight training for weight loss:  http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2010/02/01/what-burns-more-calories-cardio-intervals-or-weight-training/  "The weight training group lost 21.1 pounds of fat (44% and 35% more than diet and aerobic only groups respectively). Basically, the addition of aerobic training didn’t result in any real world significant fat loss over dieting alone."

Comment: That blog states: "Your diet is responsible for 80-90% of your successes or failures" So the form of exercise for weight loss is irrelevant, and will only change composition. Thus, the only cosmetic difference between cardio and SS is SS will increase muscle mass in the areas where the OP specifically said they didn't want it. ***I'm not anti-SS, I'm trying to point out that in this case it is the complete opposite of what the OP asked for!!!!***

Comment: This is the last thing I'm going to say on the matter, but I just respectfully think that you're flat out wrong. I even pulled out the key quote for you: *"The weight training group lost 21.1 pounds of fat (44% and 35% more than diet and aerobic only groups respectively). Basically, the addition of aerobic training didn’t result in any real world significant fat loss over dieting alone."*

Comment: Firstly, I never suggested Cardio was an answer for the OP, you drew the either SS or Cardio comparison. I just defended cardio as I enjoy it. Secondly, you haven't answered my original arguement that SS will give her muscles where the OP already clearly stated they didn't want them.

Comment: She will lose more fat than she gains in muscle and her thighs will and up being thinner. There is almost no chance that she will gain so much muscle mass that her thighs will actually be bigger than before she started.

Comment: I just wanted to add, Jeremy's proposed program is _not_ SS, so one can't expect SS-like results. In this case that is a good thing, as the OP doesn't want that. So with higher reps (= lower weights) and weekly (not daily) increases in weight this program does not aim at increasing muscle. And once the newb-gains are done, the caloric deficit will not allow for further muscle growth. If the OP is not a genetic freak 'blessed' with super fast growing muscle, this plan will likely 'tone' her thighs and that's it. I wouldn't worry about significant growth.

Answer (score 0):

First : "I don't to be like the girls who have big muscles and heavy thighs and big triceps"

It will never happen unless you're 100% dedicated and wanted to be like this.

As has been said before, you'll need to exercise and eat right if you want results. Because I have my daily 4,000 calories at McDonald's I will never be able to get in shape and I will probably be getting fat.

Also, don't over-eat salad, please don't be this girl - "I want to lose weight I eat healthy and balanced so I only eat salad."

The girl that you've linked a photo is probably never lifting weights, on maybe like 1kg biceps curl doing "swinging bowling lifting".

[There's an article who talks about HIIT training](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance/the_hiit_revolution_for_fat_burning_success) for fat burn.

If you want to be like this girl skip the following, because nutrition and HIIT training is enough to be like her.

Don't be afraid to lift "heavy" weights (but still keeping good form) because you'll not gain 25 cm of biceps in 3 months.

If you workout in a fitness center, you can ask for a workout plan and explain your wish. Otherwise, [a workout with your bodyweight](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=475aEW2KV_8) is enough!

Even if you are not going to a gym, write a workout plan like:

```
Monday : upper body
Tuesday : lower body
Wednesday : rest
Thursday : rest
Friday : full body
saturday : rest
sunday : rest
```

And add some HIIT training after the workout or on a rest day.

Have fun ! =)